# How to Search Post Code and Cities Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

Hi I have a code that searching only the cities on Australia.

How can I able to search the Post Code also?

Please see my code:

```js
function initialize() {

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'AU'
      }
    });

  ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = ac.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // Alert the selected place
    window.alert("You selected: '" + place.formatted_address + "'");
  });
}
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `regions` instead `cities` in **types** cause `cities` limited to `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3` where `regions` includes `postal_code` along with

1. locality
2. sublocality
3. country
4. administrative_area_level_1
5. administrative_area_level_2

check source : (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types)

use below updated code

```
  `var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(regions)'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'AU'
      }
    });`
```

also check updated code snippet.

```js
function initialize() {

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(regions)'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'AU'
      }
    });

  ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = ac.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // Alert the selected place
    window.alert("You selected: '" + place.formatted_address + "'");
  });
}
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
```